# Python 'map' function inserting NaN, possible to return original values instead?

Tags: python, pandas, map-function

I am passing a dictionary to the `map` function to recode values in the column of a Pandas dataframe. However, I noticed that if there is a value in the original series that is not explicitly in the dictionary, it gets recoded to `NaN`. Here is a simple example:

Typing...

```
s = pd.Series(['one','two','three','four'])
```

...creates the series

```
0      one
1      two
2    three
3     four
dtype: object
```

But applying the map...

```
recodes = {'one':'A', 'two':'B', 'three':'C'}
s.map(recodes)
```

...returns the series

```
0      A
1      B
2      C
3    NaN
dtype: object
```

I would prefer that if any element in series `s` is not in the `recodes` dictionary, it remains unchanged. That is, I would prefer to return the series below (with the original `four` instead of `NaN`).

```
0      A
1      B
2      C
3   four
dtype: object
```

Is there an easy way to do this, for example an option to pass to the `map` function? The challenge I am having is that I can't always anticipate all possible values that will be in the series I'm recoding - the data will be updated in the future and new values could appear.

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't create a dictionary entry for `four`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) instead of `map`:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(['one','two','three','four'])
>>> recodes = {'one':'A', 'two':'B', 'three':'C'}
>>> s.map(recodes)
0      A
1      B
2      C
3    NaN
dtype: object
>>> s.replace(recodes)
0       A
1       B
2       C
3    four
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 6):

If you still want to use map the map function (can be faster than replace in some cases), you can define missing values:

```
class MyDict(dict):
def __missing__(self, key):
    return key

s = pd.Series(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])

recodes = MyDict({
'one':'A',
'two':'B',
'three':'C'
})

s.map(recodes)

0       A
1       B
2       C
3    four
dtype: object
```

Comment: Could you explain more about how the class works, please?

Comment: @JamesHuang It inherits from the main dict class and overwrites the default `__missing__` method for `dict` objects.